# Ищу подобную либо такую же библиотеку для отображения/редактирования массивов в C#

Tags: диаграммы

Ищу подобную либо такую же библиотеку для отображения/редактирования массивов в C#.
Есть серия неких программ по настройке гбо на автомобилях.В них используются самые разнообразные библиотеки.На скринах одна из них.Перелопатил гугл,не нашел.Может кто сталкивался с такой или подобной?
[введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBdcg.jpg)
Нужна возможность из под windows forms c# быстро и удобно изменять значения в одномерных/двумерных массивах.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

LiveCharts, правда они WPF как раз наподобие такого сейчас и программирую, правда не для гбо а для отображения процессов в ПЛК вообще